# Run and Receive a Command in screen via PHP

Tags: php, minecraft

I'm making a Minecraft control panel, but are sort of confused on how to send a command to each screen. I understand how to execute a command to a screen, but I don't understand to read the output.

Ex. I have screen A and screen B. I want to execute something in screen A, and get the output, and then exit the screen.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague, I want to help you but I can't unless you elaborate.

Comment: What do you mean by "screen" ? Is it linux program or something else?

Comment: Ah ok, I'm incredibly sorry, let me try to explain better.

Comment: Screen is the linux program used for running sort of virtual command lines. I know of the way you can execute the command to a screen session, but there isn't a way to capture the outpost. I was wondering if there is a way to exit out of a screen via a screen session, as in simulating a key press

Comment: @user1731631 - you're referring to "[GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)".  But don't refer to it in just a comment.  If the information is necessary to make your question clear, then [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12806555/edit) and add it.  Of course, if your question is about how to use GNU Screen, then it's off-topic for StackOverflow.  For capturing output of screens, you should `man screen` and check the `-L` option, as well as search for the word "logging" throughout the man page.  But that's not what you want.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 4):

Here's an easier solution:
Use Websend bukkit plugin [(Download&info)](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/websend/) in both servers. PHP can simply execute commands and receive outputs when plugin is installed and php classes setted up, also this can be more complex than bash screen, and much easier to setup and use.

Here's an example use of this:

```
<?php
include_once 'Websend.php';

//Replace with bukkit server IP. To use a different port, change the constructor to new Websend(ip, port)
$ws = new Websend($ServerIP, $ServerPort); 

//Replace with password specified in Websend config file
$ws->connect("password");

$ws->doCommandAsConsole("give ".$PlayerName." 64 1");
$ws->disconnect();
?>
```

In this example the script item to a variable-definied player.
You can execute a custom variable command with replacing `$ws->doCommandAsConsole("give ".$PlayerName." 64 1");' to`$ws->doCommandAsConsole("$_REQUEST['customCMD']"); where customCMD is a field in a GET or POST form.`

Answer (score 2):

Don't actually need a plugin, but keep in mind using shell_exec could open a massive world of pain for you when it comes to security.

However, I was having a similar issue with implementing a control panel in drupal, I managed to run commands to a screen using the following code.

```
shell_exec("screen -S ScreenName -X stuff \"echo hello world\"'\n'");
```

You're welcome.