# How do I get a php script to send text to a Minecraft Server chat?

Tags: php, response, server, minecraft

I have set up a Bukkit Minecraft server (1.7.10), and I am using a plugin called MyCommand.

```
'website':
  command: /website
  type: CALL_URL
  url: '(my website)/bukkit-server/respond.php?action=$arg1&player=$player'
  get_output : true
  show_output_ingame : true
  save_output_as : httpResponse
```

I believe the syntax of this paragraph is correct. I want my php script on my website to return something like "Website: We recieved your command $player !" to my Minecraft Server. Here is my current php script.

```
<?php
  $mc_name = htmlspecialchars($_GET['player']);
  $action = htmlspecialchars($_GET['action']);

  //php response code
?>
```

Do I need to install some kind of socket plugin?

Answer (score 0):

According to the specification [at the bottom of this page](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/mycommand/pages/configuration-and-example/), you would need to use

```
<?php
    $mc_name = htmlspecialchars($_GET['player']);
    $action = htmlspecialchars($_GET['action']);

    echo "Website: We received you command $mc_name";
?>
```

However, that does only show that the message was received and gives feedback to the bukkit server, which then could either save, display or ignore the message. You will not be able to directly run commands for your minecraft server using only this function.

If you could combine this with a command of the `RUN-COMMAND` type, the command would be directly executed and the server notified, which could then proceed the information and, using the code above, return a message to the minecraft server.

You might also take a look at this existing question [run-and-receive-a-command-in-screen-via-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806555/run-and-receive-a-command-in-screen-via-php)